# Save data from Azure HUB-IOT to an Azure SQL-database

Tags: azure-sql-database, iot, azure-iot-hub

I have recently created an Azure Hub-IOT in which I am sending some data from a virtualized device, I know that the data arrived because I can see them from a terminal but now I want to take this data and save them into an Azure SQL_DataBase, how can I do this?

If someone can explain me the process or link some tutorial I will appreciate it.

Comment: Does this help:https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlserverstorageengine/2018/01/23/working-with-azure-iot-data-in-azure-sql-database/

Comment: Stream Analytics is of cource an easy and fast way but very expencive! I recommend using Azure Functions with dependency injection of DbContext.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write the data to IoT Hub, then you just need to create a stream Analytics Job to save the data on an Azure SQL Database:

[image]

Please read [this](https://dgkanatsios.com/2016/03/09/raspberry-pi-sense-hat-azure-iot-hub-oh-my/) tutorial for detailed information. Another useful tutorial may be [this](http://chroscielski.pl/index.php/2017/03/19/azure-iot-hub-stream-analytics-sql-database-powerbi-part-2/) one.