# Azure how to get events shown in CLI from IoT to a database

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-iot-hub

I am having some issues actually retrieving and using the data I send to the IoT Hub in Azure. When I run 'az IoT hub monitor-events --hub-name  ' in CLI I can see my events, and I can also send messages to my devices in the IoT hub.

I have then tried to create a stream, to forward the messages to my SQL database, but without any luck. Do you have any suggestions on how to retrieve this data?

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways about this. The two most common scenarios are probably using an Azure Function, or using a Stream Analytics job. I don't know what you've tried up until this point, but a Stream Analytics job is probably the easiest way to go.

### Stream Analytics

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49674134/8800237) on SO could be what you're looking for, it also links to [this tutorial](https://dgkanatsios.com/2016/03/09/raspberry-pi-sense-hat-azure-iot-hub-oh-my/) that you could follow from "Create a new Azure SQL Database" onwards. It covers creating an IoT Hub input and Azure SQL output on your Stream Analytics job and using a simple query to link the two together. There is more info in the Microsoft docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/stream-data-stream-analytics-integration?WT.mc_id=IoT-MVP-5004034)

### Azure Function

While looking this one up I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62381952/8800237), which is mine, awkward. But it describes how you can go about creating an Azure Function that accepts IoT Hub messages and shoots them to your database. This option is a lot more cost-efficient (or even free, if you use the consumption plan for a Function) for a few devices.